# Why isn't the option to create a Network Dataset available?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, network-dataset

I'm trying to create a network data set from a roads file (something that has worked before), but now for some reason the option to do it is not available. What could be the problem?

[image]

Why wouldn't the option to create one be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have your Network Analyst extension enabled.

From the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/main/using-extensions-in-arcgis.htm), to enable it:

- Select Extensions from the Customize menu in ArcMap

[image]

- Check the box next to Network Analyst

[image]